# Do Sylow's theorems apply to continuous groups in any way?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Sylows theorems are generally for discrete groups, but is there any sort of relationship between prime factorization and continuous groups?

Comment: Do you mean topological groups with nondiscrete topology? Or what does it mean for a group to be continuous?

Comment: In a connected reductive group, the Borel subgroups play the much same role as Sylow subgroups do in finite groups.

Comment: @LetGBeTheGraph Could you elaborate on that? I cannot think of any ways in which the play the same role (other than having similar properties).

Comment: I guess for Lie groups.

Comment: Although there are some partial generalizations to infinite groups (such as locally finite groups with various properties), it would be more accurate to say that Sylow's theorems are generally for finite groups.

Comment: What about maybe the complex unit circle, which as far as I know forms a Lie group? Isn't there anything special about primes there? Or isn't there anything related to p-adic analysis and Lie groups?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That is all I meant, I guess I was being too generous to them :)